# File Input doesn't store file information, just the name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-io, redux-form

I'm using `redux-form@8.1.0` and `redux@4.0.1` and saving the data in a MongoDB collection. However, when I watch the file object that I uploaded in my Mongo DBs' collection it just retrieves the name of the file.

`FileInput.js` is the component that I pass to the redux-form `Field` component

### FileInput.js

```
import React from 'react';

const handleChange = (handler) => ({target: {files}}) =>
  handler(files.length ? {file: files[0], name: files[0].name} : {});

export default ({
  input: {onChange, onBlur, value: omitValue, ...inputProps},
  meta: omitMeta,
  ...props
}) => (
  <input type="file"
    onChange={handleChange(onChange)} onBlur={handleChange(onBlur)}
    {...inputProps} {...props} />
);
```

And this is how I use it in my form

```
...
import FileInput from './FileInput';
...
<Field name="fileUploaded" component={FileInput} type="file" 
  />
```

#### And this is the document in the MongoDB collection

```
{...
"fileUploaded":{"name":"testingfile.png"},
...}
```

It seems it stores only the name of the file and I expect another key value pair with the file information/object in order to load and display this image/file later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux-Form stores the file, perhaps you need to read it out and then send it as a `multipart/form-data`. The data should be accessible at `state.form.myFormNameHere.values.mFieldNameHere`.

I made an ImageDisplay component that may be of help. It reads the file from a red-form file input and displays a preview.

```
const ImageReader = ({ file }) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState('');
    if (file && file.file instanceof Blob) {
        reader.onload = (event) => {
            const { target: { result } } = event;
            setImageUrl(result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file.file);
        return <Image src={imageUrl} />;
    }
    return <Image src={null} />;
};

ImageReader.defaultProps = {
    file: null,
};

ImageReader.propTypes = {
    file: PropTypes.shape({
        name: PropTypes.string,
        file: PropTypes.any,
    }),
};
```